# Django template does not exist @

Tags: python, django, templates

I am using python 3.7.2 and Django 2.1 and every time I try to load the home url I get the following error.

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /
>
> ghostwriters/post_list.html
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/ Django
> Version:  2.1 Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:
>
> ghostwriters/post_list.html
>
> Exception Location:
> C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\ghostwriter-HT06mH6q\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py
> in select_template, line 47 Python Executable:
> C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\ghostwriter-HT06mH6q\Scripts\python.exe

Doesn't make any sense because there really is no post_list.html and its not in my app level urls.py or my views.py so why is this happening?

urls.py:

> from django.urls import path from .views import PostListView
>
> urlpatterns = [
> path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='home'), ]

views.py:

> from django.shortcuts import render from django.views.generic import
> ListView
>
> from .models import Post
>
> class PostListView(ListView):
> model = Post
> template = 'home.html'

settings.py:

> TEMPLATES = [
> {
> 'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
> 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
> 'APP_DIRS': True,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using any CBV(Class Based Views), by default django will look for template with some specific pattern. In your case, since you are using List View, it will look for YOURMODELNAME_list.html (YOURMODELNAME in lowercase), If you are extending Detail View, it will look for YOURMODELNAME_detail.html .if you want to override this behavior, within your CBV try this,

```
class YourCBV(ListView):
   template_name = 'your_new_template.html'
```

For your reference,
[Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects)